# RPI Zero W unexpected GPIO behavior

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, python-telegram-bot, raspberry-pi-zero

EDIT: While debugging i found out that something else is wrong and my GPIO pins might just be malfunctioning, looking into it more right now.

I'm currently trying to control multiple relays with my Raspberry pi zero W through telegram. While trying to set this up i've stumbled upon some weird GPIO behavior. Whenever i load the telegram libray and i setup the GPIO pins they are set to HIGH while the default is LOW, this only happens when the library is imported. I think it has something to do with the `application.run_polling()` function because whenever thats called the GPIO pins go from LOW to HIGH without sending the ouput request to do so.

The library used is [Python telegram bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). Ive tried using different telegram bots but it does also happen with [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).

For context: I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero W with a [Grove Base Hat](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove_Base_Hat_for_Raspberry_Pi_Zero/).

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import logging
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, ContextTypes, CommandHandler

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

shutterUp = 27
shutterDown = 23
waterPump = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(shutterUp, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(shutterDown, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(waterPump, GPIO.OUT)

chatId = CHAT_NUMBER;

def isInvalidChat(messageChatId):
    if (messageChatId == chatId):
        return False
    return True

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

try:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        application = ApplicationBuilder().token('TOKEN').build()
        
        start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
        application.add_handler(start_handler)

        application.run_polling()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print("Keyboard interrupt")
finally:
   print("GPIO clean up") 
   GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO
```

Does anyone know what i could do to fix this or what could be causing this, i've tried using multiple examples from the library's but both of them have the same unwanted behavior.

TL;DR I tried setting up GPIO pins and expected them to be LOW which normally works when just doing this without an imported library. Whenever the `application.run_polling()` function is called all GPIO pins i've setup will go to HIGH and turn on the relays.

Comment: Why would you expect your output pins to be in any particular state, given that you haven't specified any state?  You need to be explicit about that: `GPIO.setup(shutterUp, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)` for example.

Comment: @jasonharper this should be the default but i will try it.